# Watch Folder - Http Request when new folder arrives with dynamic params

Tags: java, c, iis, directory

In a nutshell I need my Windows IIS server to watch a folder for a file to arrive. When that happens I want the server to sent a HTTP request to domain.com?file=filename. What is the best method to do this in the most light weight way possible.

I've been looking at IIS 7 watch folders and doing something with command prompt, but I don't know how to get the file name and run the request. I can do a chron job, but because I can have multiple files coming in/going out, I run the risk of duplicating processes, in addition I want the process to run immediately.

What would be the "best" place to start on the server. I am a web programmer and am more unfamiliar with server side technologies in this regard. Java? C? Python? Again, I'd love it if it didn't required new languages to be installed and was the most light weight possible. All I need it to do it hit a webpage with the file name in the url.

The full process...

Users upload a file via webapp.
I have a local OCR take the image and turn it into a text document and place the text document in the folder I am listening on. The web server then takes that text document and does some stuff with it.

I want that last step to happen right when the file is created. The OCR software doesn't have the ability to send a http request as far as I know. Omnipage.

Comment: Please clarify - you have a folder on your Windows box and when a file is added to it, you want to make an HTTP request to a _different_ domain? Or you want to make a request to your local IIS server (on that same machine) so you can do something with the file locally?  Maybe more context of what you're trying to set up would help.

Comment: So... yes the machine is a server. I assumed all HTTP requests would be the same, just a standard request. But yes the server is the machine where the files are located. And that server is running the webapp where the request will go.

Comment: Okay, then do you need IIS at all?  If you're looking for simple, you might consider just making a batch file, or a PowerShell script, or a bit more sophisticated: write something in Python.  The script could either loop itself and check for file changes (in some languages there are libraries to watch for file system changes in a more efficient manner); or you could just run the script once a minute to check if a new file is there and react if so - can schedule it with the "Scheduled Task" feature.  You can make an HTTP request from various languages - you don't need IIS to do that.

Comment: Well because IIS has watch folders as a plugin and it can run command line I thought it might be good. I'm fine with a looping batch running all the time. I just need something that can sent a http request but also include the file name and all my googling didn't find a way to do that from the command line.